# Jupyter Notebook - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have Python 3.7 installed on my windows 10 laptop. i installed pandas and numpy a few days ago on my laptop and they worked fine when used in my jupyter notebook by writing `import numpy as np` and `import pandas as pd`. 
But today when i started my jupyter notebook again to practice the same error occurred a quite a few times. 
[`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa7uR.png)

I tried restarting the jupyter kernel many times and then executed the statement again and again but the same error displayed each time.

I've installed numpy using `pip install numpy` and pandas using `pip install pandas`

i already tried installing pandas and numpy through my jupyter notebook using `!pip install numpy` and `!pip install pandas` but the problem remains the same.
Check out the below screenshots. Click on the link to view.

[pandas error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa7uR.png)

[numpy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsoZa.png)

I'm still learning python so can you please help me with this.
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hey, it worked. I tried following the commands from the above links. Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 30):

Open a notebook. Install your packages through the notebook by entering in a notebook cell -

```
!pip install numpy
!pip install pandas
```

Then import

Comment: i already tried what you said exactly the same but the problem still remains the same. Check my answer above where i am adding a link of two screenshots (one is the numpy error and another one for pandas error after installing it through jupyter notebook)

Comment: Have you set your environment paths?

Comment: No. How can we do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553560/jupyter-python3-notebook-cannot-recognize-pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235013/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Hey, it worked. I tried following the commands from the above links. Thank You So Much.

Comment: Great job, but you have to become better at using stack overflow. Always search for existing answers first. This one will be most likely marked duplicate

Comment: %pip install numpy
%pip install pandas

Then restart the kernel and execute the cells.

Comment: Man, you saved my life. Thank you so much. No other solutions worked. This answer is very underrated. Others, please upvote and show your gratitude if it worked for you.